# Cannot edit Yahoo Profile for a week

Tags: yahoo

When I try to edit my profile on http://profile.yahoo.com, it keeps giving this error:

```
This action could not be completed because we are currently under maintenance.
Sorry for the inconvenience. Please try again later.
```

This has been the issue since I created my Yahoo profile, one week ago. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried logging in with a different browser? I'm able to see my Yahoo profile.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail at which point you get the error

Comment: When I am logged in at my profile page I can change my profile name, add a location, make Facebook/Twitter public/private. It gives a big red bar at the top with this error message when trying t alter them though.

Comment: I'm not having any issue altering any information on my Yahoo profile. I've added/removed/readded Twitter & Facebook. I've also Edited and successfully saved all portions of my contact information. You can see my screenshot here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FwuXN.png

Comment: Thanks! When I click "Show in Profile" for FB/Twitter todisplay, it shows the error. Changing the name or replacing the avatar does not work either. I was able to connect FB/Twitter from the other setting pages and edit the contact information. Although it rejects the Dutch postal code. I guess it's time to give up and stop caring.
Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/FBysy.png